# How to prevent disposing context in .net core?

Tags: .net-core

I have an application in .NET Core 2.2 and I need some processes to run in the background. So, I separate this process with a new thread like this...

```
        Thread backgroundAction = new Thread(delegate ()
        {
            MyRealMethod();
        })
        {
            IsBackground = true
        };

        backgroundAction.Start();
```

But, there is some problem because the new thread disposes of the current context and I can't access this context anymore. Sometimes I have more than 1 context so forwarding context in the method is not an option. Is there any option to keep context alive?

Comment: Create new context inside background thread.

Comment: Please describe, how did you injected the corresponding context? And my next question is do you mean DbContext by "context" ?

Comment: Yes, it is DbContext, and I inject context trough service.AddScoped<DbContext>